# Byte Identification Based on Type

Tags: c

I am currently watching a Stanford Online Course named Programming Paradigms and had a question about a topic the professor just taught.

Say, I initialize a short in C as, `short c = 16649;` which has a corresponding bit pattern of, `0100001000001001`.

If I fool a pointer into believing that it is only a `char*` like so, `*(char*)&s`, shouldn't I get back the upper bits of s, which would correspond to the bit pattern of `01000010`, or 'A'?

Trying to print the value pointed at by the above line gives me a `' '`, instead of 65. Looking for an explanation of why this is the case.

Thank you

Comment: Upper or lower depends on the endianness of the representation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Most likely it will print the 2nd (as big endian architectures are less common that little ones - at least in PC world) which is _TAB_.

Comment: To the extent that the "PC world" implies Intel architecture, big-endian architectures are completely non-existent in that world.  I'm not sure how else to interpret the term.

Comment: Guys, what's the point in answering in comments? I don't feel right about posting answer which is already described in comments and I don't feel right about questions which are technically marked as unanswered while they are not. Is there a reason for doing so?

Comment: @nnovich-OK, it is relatively common for simple questions to be answered in comments.  This may reflect that the commenter does not think it worthwhile to spend time on writing an answer, or that the question is borderline for the site and does not deserve a formal answer, or a suspicion that it has already been asked and answered.

Comment: "If I fool a pointer into believing that it is only a `char*` like so, `*(char*)&s`, shouldn't I get back the upper bits of s, which would correspond to the bit pattern of 01000010, or 'A'?" --> no.  Its UB.

Comment: @nnovich-OK And you can take an advantage of it and write a full-blown answer yourself. But make sure it is not just repeating the comments, but give a comprehensive, self-contained and well explained information.

Comment: @chux Ok, undefined behavior, that makes sense. But should it theoretically be able to read those 8 bits and reproduce 'A' if the pattern matches?

Comment: @nnovich-OK an answer needs more effort at presentation and completeness than a comment. I prepare such answers in a text editor. On many occasions I have invested the necessary time, only to find that when my answer is ready, the question has been either closed or deleted. It can be *very* frustrating. I feel there ought to be a time limit before deletion or closing to give contributors the opportunity to make an answer.

Comment: @chux Why? It can be aliased as `char*`...

Comment: Yes its UB, so it is "theoretically be able to read those 8 bits" is a possible form of UB.  The larger question is why do this instead of writing well behaved and portable code?

Comment: It was just more of an experiment and learning experience. Thanks for all the guidance everyone!

Comment: @EugeneSh. I stand well corrected on the pointer conversion part: "When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object."  C11 §6.3.2.3 7.  The referencing of that pointer with `*` is the next problem.  Had that been a reference to an `unsigned char`, then no problem.  To a `char` is another issue.  Certainly _likely_ to not be a problem.  IAC, better to write compliant code.  IOWs, when investigating _bytes_, use `unsigned char` or maybe `uint8_t`.